# Indirect function into Averageif

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I have a dropdown list on A1, that returns on A2 what worksheet will be my datasheet *(All_Data_1, All_Data_2, All_Data_3, etc.)*

I can use it easily with other functions using the =INDIRECT(A2), like

`=VLOOKUP(B1;INDIRECT($A$2);6;)`

When B1 is my wanted text

But now, I have to use AVERAGEIF function and it doesn't give me the option to add column 6. 
I should work with something like INDIRECT($A$2[label])

in example:
`=AVERAGEIF(All_Data_1[Name];$B$1;All_Data_1[points])`

How could I work with these 2 parameters together?

Comment: Does column 6 have the same name in each of your tables? If so, you can just include the column name in your `INDIRECT()` reference.

Comment: `INDIRECT($A$2 & "[Name]")`

Comment: @ScottCraner. It worked like a charm. Thank you.